# Speeding up Python Lemmatizer with 'for' Loop and 'if' Statements

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I use this code to apply a Lemmatizer depending to the postage of a word.

```py
def lemmatize_all(sentence):
    wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
    lem = []
    for word, tag in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)):
        if tag.startswith("NN"):
            lem.append(wnl.lemmatize(word, pos='n'))
        elif tag.startswith('VB'):
            lem.append(wnl.lemmatize(word, pos='v'))
        elif tag.startswith('JJ'):
            lem.append(wnl.lemmatize(word, pos='a'))
        else:
            lem.append(word)
    return lem
```

The problem is that the more data I have, the longer it takes. Could you help me to accelerate the code please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this suits you but it sure can replicate the behavior of your code and could be expanded easily.

```
def lemmatize_all(sentence):
    wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
    lem = []

    tags = {
        'NN': 'n',
        'VB': 'v',
        'JJ': 'a',
    }

    for word, tag in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)):
        tag_start = tag[:2]
        if tag_start in tags:
            lem.append(wnl.lemmatize(word, pos=tags[tag_start]))
        else:
            lem.append(word)
    return lem
```

This way you can create a dictionary that translates tags into pos.
Or if there's more tags than poses, maybe this will come in handy:

```
def lemmatize_all(sentence):
    wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
    lem = []

    tags = {
        'n': ['NN','NA'],
        'v': ['VB','VA'],
        'a': ['JJ','JA'],
    }

    for word, tag in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)):
        tag_start = tag[:2]
        if tag_start in  tags['n']:
            lem.append(wnl.lemmatize(word, pos='n'))
        elif tag_start in  tags['v']:
            lem.append(wnl.lemmatize(word, pos='v'))
        elif tag_start in  tags['a']:
            lem.append(wnl.lemmatize(word, pos='a'))
        else:
            lem.append(word)
    return lem
```

I added tags starting with NA, VA and JA to illustrate how to expand the code.